Google Docs API Authorisation - Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
I am making an app which will extract text from an image and write that text in a new Google Document.
I have downloaded and set up the 'credentials.json' file. But I am getting an error when the API is called for Authorisation.

Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid
email@gmail.com(not the actual email)
You can’t sign in because this app sent an invalid request. You can try again later or contact the developer about this issue. Learn more about this error
If you are a developer of this app, see error details.
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

import streamlit as st
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import cv2
import tempfile
import numpy as np

from Functionalities.camera_input import get_camera_input
from Functionalities.upload_input import get_uploaded_input
from Functionalities.text_extraction import get_text_from_image
from Functionalities.docs_api import create_blank_document

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

st.title('Make notes on the go...')
use_camera = st.checkbox("Use Camera")
if use_camera:
    image_file = get_camera_input()
else:
    image_file = get_uploaded_input()

col1, col2 = st.columns(2)
show_image = col1.checkbox("Show Image")
show_text = col2.checkbox("Show Text")

image_container = st.container()
if show_image:
  with image_container:
    if image_file is not None:
      st.image(image_file)
    else:
      st.write("No image available")

if show_text:
    img_to_text = get_text_from_image(image_file)
    if img_to_text is not None:
        extracted_text = st.text_area("Extracted Text:", img_to_text, height=200)
        # User options for writing to documents (implementation not included here)
        write_to_options = st.selectbox("Write To:", ("New Document", "Existing Document"))
        if write_to_options == "New Document":
            credentials = 'credentials.json'
            if not credentials:
                st.write("Please authorize your Google account to write to Docs:")
                # Implement OAuth flow using google-auth-oauthlib to obtain credentials
            if credentials:
                doc_title = st.text_input("New Document Title:")
                if st.button("Create and Write"):
                    # Implement create_blank_google_doc function using the obtained credentials
                    doc_id = create_blank_document(credentials, doc_title)
                    # if doc_id:
                    #     # Call append_text_to_google_doc function using the obtained credentials
                    #     # append_text_to_google_doc(credentials, doc_id, extracted_text)
                    #     # st.success(f"Text appended to new document: {doc_title}")
        else:
            st.write("Existing Document functionality not implemented yet.")
    else:
        st.write("No image selected or text extraction failed.")


# CREDENTIALS_FILE = 'credentials.json'
# DOC_TITLE = "My New Document"

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

def create_blank_document(CREDENTIALS_FILE, DOC_TITLE):
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents']
    # Initialize credentials flow
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CREDENTIALS_FILE, SCOPES)
    # Get user credentials
    credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Build the Docs service object
    service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
    # Create a new document body
    body = {
        'title': DOC_TITLE
    }
    # Create the document
    document = service.documents().create(body=body).execute()
    print(f"Doc created with ID: {document.get('id')}")


please be more specific. This is to broad. Explain, where you got your credentials.json from and how you did set it up.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This is better as you share the URL of the auth endpoint, but there seems to be an Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch. I never used that API thus can't help you with it. Search the internet for that error and lookup other examples for the auth flow. Maybe you also need a personal token or URL and the right settings in Google.
